# How can I hardcode joomla 3.1 core alias generator

Tags: url, joomla, alias, sef

I am using joomla 3.1 and want to edit alias generating function for some special Turkish characters. Because it rewrites the **'Ü'** character as **'ue'**, but i want it as **'u'**. And i don't want to use unicode alias function.

- 'Ü' and 'ü' must be 'u'
- 'Ö' and 'ö' must be 'o'
- 'İ' and 'ı' must be 'i'
- 'Ş' and 'ş' must be 's'
- 'Ç' and 'ç' must be 'c'

How can i fix that?

Comment: Transliteration is part of language package (tr-TR/tr-TR.localise.php in site and admin language directories) and it should be implemented as
`<?php class tr_TRLocalise {
 public function transliterate($string) {
  /* do some magic */
  return $string;
 }
}`

Comment: Also make sure unicode URL is turned on in global Joomla. By default it is turned off. If it is on then you will see Ö or Ş in URl without transliteration.